# ¿Cómo puede hacer un bucle infinito de una función void?

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando hacer un juego de una avioneta. Estoy usando la función `gotoxy` para hacer una función `void` que es la avioneta girando su hélice. Ya lo tengo hecho, solo quiero hacer que mi función `void` se repita infinitamente.
Ya llevo mucho tiempo intentado con distintos métodos como usar de manera estratégica el Sleep o las funciones o bucles `while`, `if`, incluso el `do while`, pero no puedo.

Trabajo en dev c++, no uso codeblocks y estoy en la versión de dev c++ 6.3.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    HANDLE hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon, dwPos);
}
void nave1(int x, int y){
    gotoxy(x,y  );cout<<"            ";
    gotoxy(x,y+1);cout<<"     __     ";
    gotoxy(x,y+2);cout<<"__^__[]__^__";
    gotoxy(x,y+3);cout<<"     []     ";
    gotoxy(x,y+4);cout<<"   __[]__   ";
}
void nave2(int x, int y){
    gotoxy(x,y  );cout<<"            ";
    gotoxy(x,y+1);cout<<"     -_     ";
    gotoxy(x,y+2);cout<<"__^__[]__^__";
    gotoxy(x,y+3);cout<<"     []     ";
    gotoxy(x,y+4);cout<<"   __[]__   ";
}
void nave3(int x, int y){
    gotoxy(x,y  );cout<<"            ";
    gotoxy(x,y+1);cout<<"     _-     ";
    gotoxy(x,y+2);cout<<"__^__[]__^__";
    gotoxy(x,y+3);cout<<"     []     ";
    gotoxy(x,y+4);cout<<"   __[]__   ";
}
void nave4(int x, int y){
    gotoxy(x,y  );cout<<"            ";
    gotoxy(x,y+1);cout<<"     __     ";
    gotoxy(x,y+2);cout<<"__^__[]__^__";
    gotoxy(x,y+3);cout<<"     []     ";
    gotoxy(x,y+4);cout<<"   __[]__   ";
}
void borrar(int x, int y){
    gotoxy(x,y  );cout<<"            ";
    gotoxy(x,y+1);cout<<"            ";
    gotoxy(x,y+2);cout<<"            ";
    gotoxy(x,y+3);cout<<"            ";
    gotoxy(x,y+4);cout<<"            ";
}
void avion(int &x, int &y){
    borrar(x,y);
    nave1(x,y);
    Sleep(50);
    borrar(x,y);
    
    borrar(x,y);
    nave2(x,y);
    Sleep(50);
    borrar(x,y);
    
    borrar(x,y);
    nave3(x,y);
    Sleep(50);
    borrar(x,y);
    
    borrar(x,y);
    nave4(x,y);
    Sleep(50);  
}
int main(){
    int x = 19;
    int y = 19;
    avion(x,y);
}
```

Este es mi código; ya he hecho más intentos con más códigos pero me daba errores, no sé por qué. De todos modos aquí les dejo una parte del código.

Comment: `while (true) {/*Lo que vayas a repetir infinitamente*/}`, `do {/*Lo que vayas a repetir infinitamente*/} while (true);` y `for (;;;) {/*Lo que vayas a repetir infinitamente*/}` son opciones que tienes a la mano, y de todas puedes salir con `break` si te llega a hacer falta.

Answer (score -3):

No se que es lo que quieres hacer pero tal vez te sirva:

```
void Tu_Funcion() {
  //Codigo aqui//
}

int main() {
  int j = 1; //Numero para comparar con i
  for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) { //Definimos i y si i es menor que j incrementamos i
    Tu_Funcion(); //lamamos la funcion
    j++; //incrementamos j
  }
}
```

cada vez que se evalúa `i < j` incrementas `i` para que siga con el `for` y al final del for incrementas `j` para un bucle infinito (tambien lo puedes hacer con un `while` pero te muestro este ejemplo porque puedes hacer que solo se ejecute cierta cantidad de veces si no incrementas `j` al final del for) puedes añadir variables e incrementarlas dentro o fuera del bucle y usar esas variables como indicadores para `gotoxy(int x, int y)`

Comment: Qué ganas de complicarse... si se quiere un bucle infinito, simplemente escribe un while que nunca termine... `while(true){...`. Incrementer indefinidamente una variable de tipo `int` acabará desbordándola y no puedes asegurar el correcto funcionamiento del programa.

Comment: @Benito-B dije `tal vez te sirva` aparte yo se C no C++ (y si son lenguajes distintos no entiendo porque la gente los toma como uno solo, que es distinto a que c se pueda compilar como c++)

Comment: En todo caso un "tal vez te sirva" no es una respuesta válida. De todas maneras... incluso en C si haces un bucle infinito con un int va a desbordar el valor máximo de int... qué pasa a continuación? Y si quieres escribirlo en C puro, simplemente usas `for(;;)`  o incluso `while(1)`... no veo la necesidad de estar trabajando con dos variables cuando lo que quieres es algo que nunca se acabe.

Comment: @Benito-B  si como soy nuevo también no encuentro la diferencia pero creo que c++ es más potente en capacidad tienes mas librerías por lo tanto mas funciones y la diferencia mas notoria es que c++ está mas que nada dirigida a poo